# Подсчитать количество вхождений, вывести

Tags: python

Есть проблема. У меня есть список. Этот список генерируется рандомно. Мне нужно подсчитать количество вхождений элементов списка. Вывести тот элемент, которому соответствует наибольшее количество вхождений.

Например,

```
a = {1,2,1,2,2}

Результат: 2
```

Ума не приложу, как решить эту проблему. При чем решить её надо не используя функций и методов. Т.е. - циклами....

Внизу прикреплю код. Но он не работает правильно (на уровне поиска вхождений). Как искать максимальное количество вхождений и выводить соответствующее значение я вообще не догадался.

Нужна ваша помощь!

P.S. Я новичок, не бросайте камнями, пожалуйста

```
import random
spisok = []
spisok2 = []
KolPovt = 0


for i in range(0,5):
    spisok.append(random.randint(1,3))



for i in range(1,4):
    if spisok[i-1] == spisok[i+1]:
        spisok2.append(spisok[i])
    elif spisok[i] == spisok[i-1]:
        spisok2.append(spisok[i])
    elif spisok[i] == spisok[i+1]:
        spisok2.append(spisok[i])

print('Сгенерированы такие числа: ')
print(spisok)

print(spisok2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно завести словарь, где вы будете подсчитывать количество вхождений для каждого из элементов словаря, то есть:

1. Инициализировать словарь: `dct = {}`.
2. Создать цикл, который будет
   проверять наличие элемента в словаре по значению из списка. Если он
   существует - добавить единицу, нет - добавить новый элемент в
   словарь и добавить к нему единицу.

Выглядит это вот так:

```
for i in spisok:
        if i in dct:
            dct[i] += 1
        else:
            dct[i] = 1
```

Далее вы можете вывести словарь в порядке убывания и посмотреть, какое число сколько раз встретилось:

```
for i in sorted(dct):
    print("'%d':%d" % (i,dct[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Универсальный алгоритм для произвольного набора чисел довольно сложен,
поэтому для приведенного ниже решения составлен упрощенный алгоритм именно под эту задачу.

```
import random

spisok = []
kolP1 = 0
kolP2 = 0
kolP3 = 0
i = 0

for i in range(0,5):
    spisok.append(random.randint(1,3))

for i in range(0,5) :
    if spisok[i] == 1:
        kolP1 = kolP1 + 1
    if spisok[i] == 2:
        kolP2 = kolP2 + 1
    if spisok[i] == 3:
        kolP3 = kolP3 + 1

print('Сгенерированы такие числа: ', spisok)
if kolP1 >= 2 :
     print("Число 1: имеет max N1 = ",kolP1," вхождений")
if kolP2 >= 2 :
     print("Число 2: имеет max N2 = ",kolP2," вхождений")
if kolP3 >= 2 :
     print("Число 3: имеет max N3 = ",kolP3," вхождений")
```

Comment: Ваше решение не слишком удачное, оно полагается на конкретный весьма малый  набор элементов, о чём в вопросе не сказано. В общем случае такие задачи решаются применением какого-либо вида словаря, как в принятом ответе.